# Mysql: Accessing information_schema crashes the mysql service

Tags: php, mysql, windows, crash, information-schema

i have Windows 7 64bit with Mysql 5.5.28 installed and when i try to access  information_schema tables via php mysql query the entire mysql.exe service crashes and i have to restart it.

I tried to access the information_schema via  Phpmyadmin, to make sure I'm not doing something wrong in my query but it crashes as well.

I tried to run repair command on the information_schema db, but it did not helped.

I have no idea what could be wrong with it. I did not changed any values there, i only access information_schema to read auto_increment values for my tables, but thats it.

Any advice appreciated, thanks.

Comment: What happens when you run: `SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE 'tablename'` where `tablename` is the table you want the auto increment for.

Comment: Hmm, that seems to work without a problem.

Comment: What is written in your mysql error log?

Comment: I can't find the error log file, it's not in the data directory and file search didn't found it either, it seems like it didn't generated any error.

Comment: Well then you don't need information schema. My query gets you the auto increment value. You do have a problem there, though.